# Is there any way disable caching in webview inflated through proteus

Tags: android, json, webview, flipkart-api, proteus

Need to disable the cache on `WebView`s inflated through [Proteus](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus).

> Are there any attributes on the `WebView` which can be used to disable it?

We could find the view normally would if it was inflated using precompiled XML layouts using `findViewById(R.id.something)` and call the following methods on it.

```
WebView wv = parent.findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();

ws.setAppCacheEnabled(false); 
ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE)
```

> But since [proteus](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus) inflates layouts using `JSON` from the server I cannot find the view like this and the solution would not scale for multiple `WeView`s.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you elaborate a little? If you want to call the `setCache` methods like you mentioned through proteus you can add a custom attribute handler.

Comment: I want to do operations on view once they are rendered through proteus  like we do when xml inflate the view in this case webview using findviewbyid. in this case what is happening i am loading link of html  store on our server   in webview through proteus but when we chnage html webview load previous html due to caching i want disable that caching but how to do it when i cant use findviewbyid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a custom attribute handler say `disableCache` for the WebView and solve your problem.

```
ProteusBuilder builder;
builder.register("WebView, "disableCache", new BooleanAttributeProcessor<WebView>() {
     @Override
     public void setBoolean(WebView view, boolean value) {
         WebSettings ws = view.getSettings();
         if (value) {
             ws.setAppCacheEnabled(value); 
             ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
         }
     }
});
Proteus proteus = builder.build();
ProteusContext context = proteus.createContextBuilder(context).build();

layoutInflater = context.getInflater();
```

Use `layoutInflater` to inflate your layout and then in your layout set the attribute to `true` or `false` as you please.

```
{
  "type": "WebView",
  "disableCache": "true"
}
```

You can register the custom attribute handler with your instance of `Proteus` and it will start working. The benefit is that you can toggle the flag based on your requirements and avoid hard coding cache disabled for all web views inflated through proteus.